# How to parse Nokogiri/libXML XML errors to human-friendly errors?

Tags: nokogiri, libxml2

We are using Nokogiri to validate XML files using a XSD. The problem is that the error messages that Nokogiri generates are not very friendly and very hard to translate:

```
"Element '{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}infNFe': The attribute 'Id' is required but missing."
```

Does anyone know of a parser or any other way to capture the info needed from the error to generate a more human friendly error?

Until then, we will be doing a custom parser for them... ouch!

Comment: What are you considering a "more human friendly error"?

Comment: I've build a parser that in the end does this: https://gist.github.com/victormartins/9185529

This way my client can show the error messages in anyway they want, just translating the errors in the yml file like thet do for everything else. I will release a gem whem I'm done, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a gem for this that is now open source: https://rubygems.org/gems/xml_errors_parser

It seems to work pretty well so far, but number of errors parsed is very few for now. It is however very easy to add new errors, so we will be adding them as needed.

Code reviews and pull requests are always great :)